# Problems With VS2008 Pro Edition 90 day Trial

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-vista, installation

I have two computers.  One computer is an old XP and the other is a new Vista.
I have dowloaded and pretty much tested an installation of VS2008ProEdition90dayTrialENUX1435622.iso without any problems on the XP computer.
The Vista computer (where I need to do my work and where I have all the hard drive space, etc) has been pretty eventful -- in a bad way.
It seemed that the iso file, itself did not download correctly.  So I did it a few times.  When I ran the installer, it did some sort of file extraction on a first step (71 files, I remember) and it seemd to die on the same file.
My Vista computer has a brand new OS and a brand new hard drive.  I do not understand why it is giving me so much trouble.
Eventually I resorted to FTP'ing the iso file along with all the extracted files from my XP computer to my Vista computer.
Then I managed to get further.
But it still behaves strangely.
One thing I notice is that the license agreement is missing.
[image]
That is pretty wierd.
When I get to the point where I am supposed to start the installation, the installer lights up with errors.
There are so many that I do not know where to begin.
[image]
Where do I begin?
I have tried running the iso from a virtual drive with the DAEMON toolset. That did not make a difference.
I have tried running as an Administrator.  That did not make a difference.
I have tried shutting down all programs and even uninstalling anti-virus programs.  That did not make a difference.
I have used the windows DVD burn utility to burn the files onto a DVD and run it from there.  That did not make a difference.

And the wierdness continues.  The   C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_error_vs_procore_90.txt
has error messages that read that there is a problem copying from the F drive.  Well, I do not have an F drive.

I have even gone so far is to create a virtual F drive through a network connection to myself pointing to the DVD drive.
That did not work either.

Any suggestions?

Yes, I have posted this question with the Microsoft People.  I am waiting for an answer.  Maybe StackOverflow can beat them.

Comment: Vista sucks, didn'tcha know?! Maybe it's time for you to 'upgrade' to Windows XP!! But seriously, this is probably an issue with the downloaded .iso.

Comment: I have no problems running VS2008 on Vista.

Comment: I can confirm no issues with VS2008 on XP SP2, XP SP3, Vista SP1, 2008 Server using ISO and physical media. As others have mentioned, post your error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my computer came with a NERO 7 essentials CD.
I installed this product and I noticed that there was an option to "burn an existing image" onto a cd or dvd.
I did that.
And I ran the newly created DVD as if it were a new product.

My first indication that things were working now was that the product license came up.

And now the entire installation is running smoothly.

Solved

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install MSI 4.5, .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 and then run the Visual Studio 2008 setup (as administrator) - in this way you will have a chance to a better error message.

**EDIT:** I am using [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/download.html) for installation from ISO, so far it worked just fine (in windows xp and windows server 2003/2008 with Visual Studio 2008 trial, Visual Studio 2008 SP1, and MSDN).

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone seen Microsoft's requirements for VS2008 trial? They are:

- Computer with a 1.6 GHz or faster processor
- 384 MB of RAM or more (768 MB of RAM or more for Windows Vista)
- 2.2 GB of available hard-disk space
- 5400 RPM hard drive
- 1024 x 768 or higher-resolution display
- DVD-ROM Drive
- Additional features may require Internet access. Fees may apply.

"5400 RPM hard drive"! Not "5400 RPM or faster hard drive". Does this mean my 10K RPM grunters won't work?

Anyway, enough ranting. Some things to try:

1/ I don't trust installing from ISOs (your comment on the F drive points to DAEMON tools as a possible problem there). I also don't trust Microsoft burning utilities. Try burning with a decent program and see if that helps. Or get 7zip and extract all the files from the ISO to an install directory on your hard disk and install it from there.

2/ The lack of a license indicates the file was corrupt. This may have been the downloaded file or the possible fact that you FTP'ed it across in ASCII mode.

3/ Check the filesize and md5sum of the ISO against the one you successfully installed on XP.

4/ Post the log file (or the errors from it at least) so we can help you out.

Comment: Aren't software requirements usually posted as "Minimum System Requirements" ? If that's so in this case, the "5400 RPM or faster" part would be taken for granted.

Comment: You'd think so, but all the other ones say "or faster", "or more" and so on.